# I am unable to find /home/user/Personal/Documents files in /home/ramendu/Personal/Documents

Tags: server, users, development, user-management, anydesk

Unknowingly I have deleted my `/home/user/Personal/Documents` files. How can I recover them?

[[image: 148B1.png]

Answer (score 1):

It's confusing to create a new Documents directory at `/home/ramendu/Personal/Documents` instead of storing documents in the default Documents directory. The missing documents are possibly stored in your default Documents directory at `/home/ramendu/Documents`, not at `/home/ramendu/Personal/Documents` Otherwise you could try recovering the lost documents with testdisk or extundelete from the default Ubuntu repositories.